# What is a good evergreen barrier plant in the midwest of the United States?

Tags: trees, shrubs, landscaping

These plants will be near the base of another treelike and need to be ok with partial to no sun, and then obviously full sun in the winter time.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that this shade would ideally reach to at least 6 feet. Additionally, there are deer that roam through our yard occasionally.

Comment: A photo of the area you're writing about would be helpful, as would any height and/or width requirements. Another thing - does your neighborhood harbor any deer?

Answer (score 1):

Upright yews will do well in shade. They do not grow fast and could be costly if you need many. They seemed flexible on soil requirements as they grew in sandy and clay rich soils ( in IL.).The foliage is mildly toxic , I bet deer will not bother them.

Comment: Can you add more detail to your answer?  Recommend a variety, soil conditions....